# Email messaging : Didn't understand relationship 'Responsable_ADV__r' in field path. If you are attempting

Tags: email

I'm facing a problem here.

i'm trying to send an email to Responsable_ADV__c of the owner , it's lookup field of a user in user objet.

Salesforce doesn't like this : Owner.Responsable_ADV__r.email

vente__c is a custom object.

Here is my code :

```
public static void SentEmailToADV(set<Id> vente){

     //query on template object
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'AE012_commandeX3'];

    //list of emails
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

     for(Vente__c ven : vente)
     {
         if(ven.OwnerID.Responsable_ADV__c != null)
         {
            Vente v=[select ownerid, id,Owner.Responsable_ADV__r.email from Vente__c where id=:trigger.newMap.keySet()];

             String userName = ven.Owner.Responsable_ADV__c.getUserName();

             //initiallize messaging method
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            //set object Id
            singleMail.setTargetObjectId(ven.Owner.manager.email);

            //set template Id
            singleMail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);

            //flag to false to stop inserting activity history
            singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            singleMail.setToAddresses(userEmail);

            //add mail
            emails.add(singleMail);
         }

     }
     //send mail
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

}
```

I have this error in the title's topic.

Could you please help.

Thanks in advance,
Mehdi

Comment: If using Eclipse, you can click on the schema file in your project and then build the query through point and click (by going to Vente__c and then following the relationship fields up through User (owner) and then Responsable_ADV__c to verify the actual syntax you need

Answer (score 1):

Your code has both the following

```
ven.OwnerID.Responsable_ADV__c != null
```

and

```
select Owner.Responsable_ADV__r.email from Vente__c
```

OwnerID.Responsable_ADV__c is probably wrong.